# Logging user out crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

In my SettingsVC, I send a Notification of `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogOut")` which is observed by the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Upon getting the notification, I call `User.logout` which clears all user data and then the app crashes in the `DispatchQueue` block.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = .white

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogOut"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
        User.logout()

        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([WelcomeViewController()], animated: false)
        }
    }

    if let _ = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "loggedIn") {
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
    } else {
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: WelcomeViewController())
    }

    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

The crash happens without any additional info. Any idea how to make this not crash? Thanks!

Comment: do you know, after `User.logout()`, before `setViewControllers`, how many ViewControllers are in the navigation stack?

Comment: Two. Maybe there's a strong reference somewhere. Is that what you're getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should "clear" the navigation stack before calling `setViewControllers`, moreover:

> launch the main thread synchronously from a background thread before it exits

is logically wrong, better using `async` in this way:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "LogOut"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
  User.logout()
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([WelcomeViewController()], animated: false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Same crash happening

Comment: Andrea is definitely correct that `sync` is wrong here, and may lead to a main queue deadlock (which would terminate the app after a few seconds). Popping to root probably isn't necessary. But what is the actual crash? There is usually a message in the logs that will likely tell you the problem.

Comment: Since my SettingsVC was presented, I also had to do `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`